# Avoiding messiness with debug stuff in code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging, coding-style, code-cleanup

When I write something, half the effort tends to go into adding clear and concise debug output, or **functionality** that can be enabled/disabled when that something needs debugging.

An example of **debug functionality** is a downloader class where I can turn on a #define which makes it "pretend" to download the file and simply hand me back the one I have already. That way I can test to see what happens when a user downloads a file, without having to wait for the network to physically grab the file every single time. This is great functionality to have, but the code gets messier with the #ifdefs.

I eventually end up with a bunch of `#define`s like

```
// #define DEBUG_FOOMODULE_FOO
// #define DEBUG_BARMODULE_THINGAMAJIG
// ...
```

which are uncommented for the stuff I want to look at. The code itself turns out something like

```
- (void)something
{
    #ifdef DEBUG_FOOMODULE_FOO
    DebugLog(@"something [x = %@]", x);
    #endif
    // ...
    #ifdef DEBUG_FOOMODULE_MOO
    // etc
}
```

This works great for writing / maintaining the code, but it does nothing for the appearance of the code.

How do people write effortless on-the-fly long-term debug "stuff" anyway?

Note: *I'm not only talking about NSLogging here*... I'm also talking about stuff like the pretend-download above.

Comment: Curious: is there a problem with leaving `NSLog` statements in a release build?  Does it hurt performance, fill the device logs, or otherwise provide undesirable results?

Comment: Apple does mention that you should remove NSLog entries from your code when releasing it so I think it does, yes. (I can't actually find this but I'm almost certain I've read it on developer.apple.com somewhere when I started coding.)

Comment: I believe I remember reading that somewhere as well.  Probably not a bad idea.  Maybe next version of the app I will add the macro and search/replace.

Comment: I've seen performance hits in my apps with NSLog statements in them. Leaving them in does hurt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read several libraries before writing my own and saw two approaches: macro + C functions ([NSLogger](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger/blob/master/Client%20Logger/LoggerClient.h)) or macro + Singleton ([GTMLogger](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMLogger.h), [Cocoa Lumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack/blob/master/Lumberjack/DDASLLogger.h)).

I wrote my naive implementation [here](https://github.com/j4n0/xcode4/tree/master/templates/Project%20Templates/Jano/Window%20Based.xctemplate/Classes/generic/log) using macro + singleton. I do this during runtime:

```
[Logger singleton].logThreshold = kDebug;
trace(@"hi %@",@"world); // won't show
debug(@"hi %@",@"world);
```

You could do the same for packages instead log levels. If I want it gone, I change the #defines. Here is the code involved:

```
#define trace(args...) [[Logger singleton] debugWithLevel:kTrace line:__LINE__ funcName:__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ message:args];

if (level>=logThreshold){
  // ...
}
```

If you want something more sophisticated look into Lumberjack, it has a register class facility to toggle logging for some classes.

Comment: Looked around a bit. I guess the biggest problem is that I sometimes also include special code for debugging purposes that is inside of those #defines. I'm starting to realize that this is perhaps a bad approach no matter how you do it... :/

Answer (score 1):

Having two functions and then select them appropriately either at run-time or when compiling seems like a clean approach to me. This makes it possible to have one `download.c` and one `download_debug.c` file with the same functions except with different implementations. Then link with the appropriate one if you are building with -DDEBUG or not.

Otherwise, using function pointers works as well for run-time selecting functions.

If you insist of having debug code interspersed throughout your functions, you are pretty much setting up yourself for a mess :) But, you can of course break out those snippets into  separate functions and then do the above (or make them no-ops as in the DLog example).

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you could have separate logging macros, say `MooLog` and `FooLog`, that all conditionally compile based upon separate flags.

```
#ifdef DEBUG_FOO
#   define FooLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#   define FooLog(...)
#endif

#ifdef DEBUG_MOO
#   define MooLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#   define MooLog(...)
#endif
```

Your complex logic everywhere now becomes this:

```
- (void)something
{
    // This only gets logged if the "DEBUG_FOO" flag is set.
    FooLog(@"something [x = %@]", x);
    // This only gets logged if the "DEBUG_MOO" flag is set.
    MooLog(@"Something else [y = %@]", y);
}
```

Comment: Well, I simplified it to NSLog in the code above but I'm already using code that does this. What I am asking about is having where you can enable / disable "debug modules". I guess I could write a bunch of #define functions for each of those modules to cut down on the #if's but isn't there some better way to do this? :|